# php mysql validation error

Tags: php, mysql

I know this question have been asked before and I've searched it but couldn't get to solve my problem. whenever I run this code, I get "invalid login" message. username and password is saved in mysql database. Below is my code.

```
<?php
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $db = "mydb";

    $dbconnect= mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db);
    mysqli_select_db($dbconnect,$db) or die("could not connect to database");


    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $username = stripslashes($username);
        $password = stripslashes($password);

        $query = "SELECT * from users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($query);

        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($count==1){
            echo "Login successufull!!!";
            exit();
        }else{
            echo "Invalid login";
            exit();
        }       
    }
?>

<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href='style.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<body>
    <form action = 'main.php' method="post" enctype='multipart/data-form'>
        <h1>User login information</h1>
        <p>Username:<input type= 'text' name='username'></p>
        <p>Password:<input type = 'password' name = 'password'></p>
        <p><input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value='Submit'></p>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: look at this line very carefully `$result = mysqli_query($query);` - what's missing? deviated from your other question's method http://stackoverflow.com/q/33593455/

Comment: @ChristianVarga don't you think this line `stop programming a pick up another career`  kinda harsh ? we don't know that which purpose he is using this. You can suggest something but thats not mean the harsh way

Comment: this doesn't help you `echo "Invalid login";` get the real error.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi no, it is not harsh. There are laws that exist in many industries to protect consumer safety/identity, and severe punishment to those who break it. But there is currently no law against storing passwords in plain text. You do understand the risk associated with storing a password in plain text, right? It is up to developers to do the right thing and store passwords properly to avoid placing unnecessary risk on the users that interact with their software. If they don't want to do that, then they shouldn't be writing software.

Comment: @Fred thanx for your suggestion and I appreciate you not providing me direct answer and forced me to look myself in problem.

Comment: @ChristianVarga thanx for the link on encrypting passwords. just to let you know I'm not a programmer and I'm not using this code anywhere. I'm learning coding and this was just a practice lesson. I'll move on to hashing password after this. anyway thanx for taking time and commenting on my post.

Comment: @christianVarge . Perhaps it's a project for his personal use and he's experimenting with code. It doesn't mean he plans to deploy this into a production environment. Yes it's not secure we get it, your comment was unwarranted and un constructive

Comment: @Edward I posted a link to a resource that explains why passwords need to be hashed and salted, and how to do it. I'm sorry that you feel providing help to other users is unconstructive. After 5 years of answering questions here, I'm done. I certainly want no part in a community that not only actively encourages bad development practices, but also punishes those who provide advice.

Comment: @Sachin You're welcome. I like it when people are able to figure things out for themselves (a slight nudge helps). Being a problem solver myself, is something I have done throughout my entire life, and not just in coding (wink). I'm glad to hear that you solved your question, and remember to *stay safe*, and use a good password hashing method. *Cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- ya, password hashing is the next step in process, just started looking in to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if it works. I used this as a test with my private server. It works fine. If this doesn't work for you then echo out `$username` and `$password` to see what they contain then see if they match your database.

```
<?php
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $db = "mydb";

    $dbconnect= mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db);
    mysqli_select_db($dbconnect,$db) or die("could not connect to database");


    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $username = stripslashes($username);
        $password = stripslashes($password);

        $query = "SELECT * from users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query);

        $count = mysqli_num_rows($dbconnect, $result);

        if($count == 1){
            echo "Login successufull!!!";
            exit();
        }else{
            echo "Invalid login";
            exit();
        }       
    }
?>
```

HTML:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='style.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action = 'main.php' method="post" enctype='multipart/data-form'>
            <h1>User login information</h1>
            <p>Username:<input type= 'text' name='username'></p>
            <p>Password:<input type = 'password' name = 'password'></p>
            <p><input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value='Submit'></p>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe i am missing something but how does `mysqli_query` even work without the connection object. to my understanding it is either `$dbconnect->query($query)` or `mysqli_query($dbconnect,$query)`

Comment: @Memor-X code was not working, i was getting same error and i echoed the username and password and it was retrieving correct user info. Now i've figured out what was the problem and code is working fine now. thanx for taking time and replying.